# Web Based Editors of DOT don't display fill color?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am doing my best to learn the DOT language in order to make node & edge diagrams. There are two web based editors that let you enter code and immediately see implementation: edotor.net and graphviz-visual-editor. But I've tried the code for giving a node a fill color and the editor doesn't indicate there's any error, but the display doesn't show it. Here's a simple sample code to demonstrate a node named 'a' with a yellow fill:

```
digraph {
  a [fillcolor = yellow]
}
```

...which instead gives me a node named 'a' with no fill. Or white fill. Changing the color of a node outline or an edge works fine...

I considered that maybe just the web display can't show it, but downloading it as a png looks the same

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is this just something the web based DOT editors can't do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need the attribute `style=filled`.  Like so:

```
digraph {
  a [style=filled fillcolor = yellow]
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! Why on Earth is that not made clear in the Documentation for using fillcolor in DOT?

Comment: Playing around with this now that I have my answer, I noticed something that may be of interest to anyone with the same question: 

bgcolor can set the fill color for the graph as a whole, but for a cluster you can use bgcluster=yellow OR [style=filled fillcolor = yellow] interchangably

Comment: @SergeiAlderman,  the [documentation](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fillcolor/) says this. Citate: `Assuming style=filled`. There are also [examples](https://graphviz.org/gallery/) on the site where you can see the code.